# ipython receiving control characters in iTerm2

Tags: bash, ipython, zsh, iterm2

If I initialize ipython using iTerm2 and press enter ipython receives extra control characters. How do I debug this?

I've tried using bash instead of zsh and same problem happens in iTerm2. I don't experience the problem in terminal which defaults to bash. Also tried a different keyboard and new ipython profile. Seems to be something iTerm2 or shell is being loaded with.

Mac 10.14.3

```
$ ipython                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 27 2018, 07:35:06)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.0.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:

^[[21;1RIn [1]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug. Updated ipython and defaulted iTerms color theme and problem resolved: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11336